# Select element as part of the text flow

Tags: html, css, forms, xhtml

I've got a little problem with displaying a select element on my web page. I'm trying to show a select element as part of the text flow, so that a user doesn't notice it's actually a select element (apart from the border underneath). It should act just like a regular word. Currently I have this HTML code:

```
<form method="get" action="population.php">
<p>Just show me information about only: <select name="f"><option>a</option><option>b</option></select>.</p>
</form>
```

And with that this CSS code:

```
form {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: inline;
}
form select {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: auto;
    border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2C5E93;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    display: inline;
}
```

This code doesn't work. It should be like the first picture I put below. However, in Safari the select item is forced into the first item on the row, so that the select element is before "only: " (second picture below). In Firefox on the other hand, the select element is put onto a new row altogether.

[image: The goal][image: Safari]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks on forehand!

Comment: I would use a real label in a form with a form control... but what is surrounding your form? How wide is the container that the text is sitting in? You say Firefox is making a new row... is this because of text wrapping?

Comment: Mmm, great idea! My form is surrounded by a div with a width of 240 pixels. The text is indeed wrapping. However, even if I use a label with a select item in it, it still doesn't work: in Safari the select element is forced to the first item of the row as soon as the text wraps. In Camino the select element is put unto a new row. And when I put the select element after the label, the select element is put onto a new row in both browsers... Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I think you need to update your code, give us more surrounding elements. Whenever I write a form, before I add in CSS, labels are naturally next to selects and other inputs... no newlines are created by default, and most browsers seem to make inputs/etc inline-blocks (or inlines). So maybe some more surrounding HTML and relevant CSS, or a JS fiddle... would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
    .seldiv { display: inline; }
</style>

select
<div class="seldiv">
    <select>
        <option>123</option>
        <option>456</option>
    </select>
</div>
any
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Firstly I can't put a <div> in a <p>, because the <p> is than automatically closed by the browser. Even if I change the <div> into a <span>, it still doesn't work. Then the text on the first row doesn't wrap anymore: it continues even out of the parent <div>. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I just rechecked it and it really doesn't work on my end... Maybe you don't see the problem, because it is in your example is not a child of a paragraph. Or not a child of a form?

Comment: I just tried your exact code. See [it](http://picshare.ru/view/97616/111111.png.html).

Comment: Maybe that's because your code isn't contained in an other div width a relatively small width? I'm using Camino 2.0.8 with Gecko engine (= Firefox engine) 1.9.0. Are you using a newer version? And nonetheless, this doesn't work in Safari... What do you think?